# Different accuracy for the same code in text classification in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, text-classification

I'm training a recurrent neural network based on LSTM for text classification and I have a strange behaviour. With the same code and same training set I obtain very different level of accuracy.

I know it's normal to have different value but sometimes i get value of 40% accuracy and others 90%. How is it possible?

Moreover sometimes I get "stuck" on the accuracy level, I mean that the loss and the accuracy doesn't change during the different epochs so both values remain the same. which is the  explanation for this?

Another aspect that I'm not sure that i truly understand is the fact of the padding for my input text (I'm using training in batch). I think, since I'm using a RNN, should be better use a left padding. Do you know how to pad the input? Is better left or right padding?

Last question is how to choose the number of layer and the number of node. I know that for someone the best approach is by experiment but some suggestion could be useful.

This is the implementation of my RNN:

```
sentence_indices = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype=np.int32)
embedding_layer =  pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index, emb_dim)

embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)   
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(embeddings)
X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
X = LSTM(128)(X)
X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
X = Dense(num_activation, activation='softmax')(X)
X =  Activation('softmax')(X)
model = Model(sentence_indices, X)
```

- the embeddings layer came from GloVe, a model pre-trained.
- I'm using 5 categories and 300 samples more or less
- My training set is not uniform

I'll appreciate any hint of the question above and also some suggestion to improve my neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you training over the same amount of epochs?

One of the things that could happen is that you have exploding gradients in some of the runs. Maybe you could introduce gradient clipping ([gradient clipping in keras](https://keras.io/optimizers/)) to avoid that problem. You could also use regularization ([keras ruglarizers](https://keras.io/regularizers/)) to have another measurement in place.
When it comes to padding than right padding is the usual thing to do as far as I know. The rationale is that the initial hidden state is always 0 for the sequences that come in. Otherwise you start of with different hidden stated depending on how much padding you had to the left.

In your model there is one problem. You have twice a softmax layer. So it is sufficient to just have

```
X = Dense(num_activations, activation='softmax')(X)
```

You don't need the Activation Layer next.

Do you just use 300 samples for the training or the test? For training this seems like very few samples, more would be better. You could try to make the LSTM bigger (e.g 512) if you have the computational resources for that. But if you just have 300 samples that won't make a difference in terms of performance I guess. Something else that you could try is to tweak hyperparameters like the optimizer and learning rate. And you could try to use CNN instead of LSTM, maybe that would also increase the performance a bit.

Comment: unfortunately I have only that samples. 
- I tried to do LSTM bigger but I don't see any benefit but maybe with a longer training this should work.
- I have different number of word on each email. The avarage is 410. Now I'm using 300 words and this seems to have the best performance even though I didn't expect that. Do you have any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the high value of dropout that you are using despite not using a very deep network. Dropouts are random and using a value as high as 0.5, twice, is definitely going to give you drastically varying results. Dropouts are generally kept somewhere around 0.2 - 0.3 and the highest values are only for deeper networks to avoid overfitting. Try getting rid of the dropout or keeping it around 0.15.